# How to store Map<String,BigDecimal> in db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have entity account that should have  map of currencies with the balance(Bigdecimal)

How could i store such information, i would imagine i would need a separate table that contain foreign key account id, any suggestions would be appreciated , i am just learning, thank you

```
    @Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long accountId;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    // ->> account  should contain the map bellow or foreign key to another table
    //Map<String, BigDecimal> balances;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "balances_mapping", 
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "balance_id")})
@MapKeyColumn(name = "account_id")
@Column(name = "balances")
private Map<String, BigDecimal> balances;
```

Or by using join table

```
@ElementCollection
@Immutable
@MapKeyColumn(name = "ACCOUNT")
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_BALANCE")
@JoinTable(name = "ACCOUNT_BALANCES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID"))
private Map<String, BigDecimal> accounts;

create table ACCOUNT (
  ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER not null  constraint FR_ACCOUNT_PK primary key,
)

create table ACCOUNT_BALANCE  (
  ACCOUNT_ID      NUMBER        not null constraint  FK_ACCOUNT_ID references ACCOUNT,
  ACCOUNT_NAME    VARCHAR2(100) not null,
  ACCOUNT_BALANCE NUMBER(100) not null
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for mapping a map with basic types. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/collections.html (Example 26)

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe your data model is wrong.

Have you try to change your map to something like a List of another entity with 2 field currency and balance

This will make your code more clear and you will be able to add other value to this entity later.

```
@Table()
public class Balance{
  private String currency;
  private BigDecimal balanceAmount
}
```

And if sometimes you need to use the property given by the map you can use Stream and do something like this.

```
account.getBalances().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Balance::getCurrency, Balance::getBalanceAmount)
```